# How do I restrict UIControlEventTouchUpInside for a circular UIButton to only inside the circle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I've checked out other questions for creating a circular button, that works great -

button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.height/2;

However, I find that the button responds to UIControlEventTouchUpInside for the entire original frame. How to I make it respond to the UIControlEventTouchUpInside event only inside of the circular layer?

Thanks,
Sridhar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your subclass of UIButton with following code:
(not fully accurate, because we expect that button width == button height)

```
@implementation RoundedButton

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGFloat radius = self.bounds.size.height / 2;
    //
    CGFloat x = radius - point.x;
    CGFloat y = radius - point.y;
    //
    if (x*x + y*y < radius*radius)
        return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
    else
        return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Splendid!!! Works like a charm! On a slightly unrelated note, I found that awakeFromNib is the best place to set the cornerRadius for the RoundedButton. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is implementing 
`-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`, 
`- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and 
`- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` since you need to check the hitbox on every touch. Simply, check if the distance(center, touchPosition) is smaller than buttonRadius.